# ARIMA doesn't give 80 -95 % confidence interval values for the insample data on using fitted

Tags: r, forecasting, arima

I know I can use fitted method to get the prediction of insample data . But when i print the fitted result, it doesn't give 80 and 95% confidence interval values. How do i get those values as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You naively can use the overall standard deviation of the errors and multiply it by +- the appropriate z value to get the prediction limits for each fitted point. Since the parameters and model form are estimated using the entire data set these confidence limits are a bit illogical and misleading at best. A more correct way is to just use the observations up to each point to get the standard deviation and use the prediction for 1 period out and it's confidence limits . But the problem approach with this is that your model parameters are going to change with increased sample size as you move through time. The real question is "why do you want to do what you specified" .

Comment: I think your question is valid as it is all about statistics .... but that is just my opinion.